# Windows Server 2003 VPN and Local network

Tags: windows-server-2003, vpn

I have some problems reaching local network , where VPN Windows 2003 server stands.
I have a network, which has a VPN server  (LAN ip 10.0.0.201). I created a VPN 
server on that server with different subnet for VPN users (10.0.5.0). After VPN connection is 
initiated , i am able to acces only 10.0.0.201, but not other PC, which belongs to that network (
all i need to access 10.0.0.203 and 10.0.0.208). I think i need to add somethink to static route table, 
or not?

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>route PRINT

IPv4 Route Table

Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric

```
      0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.0.0.254       10.0.0.201     10

     10.0.0.0        255.0.0.0       10.0.0.201       10.0.0.201     10

   10.0.0.201  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1        127.0.0.1     10

     10.0.5.1  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1        127.0.0.1     50
```

10.255.255.255  255.255.255.255       10.0.0.201       10.0.0.201     10

```
    127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0        127.0.0.1        127.0.0.1      1

    224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0       10.0.0.201       10.0.0.201     10
```

255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255       10.0.0.201       10.0.0.201      1

Default Gateway: 10.0.0.254

Persistent Routes:
  None

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>ipconfig /all

PPP adapter RAS Server (Dial In) Interface:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Description . . . . . . . . . . . : WAN (PPP/SLIP) Interface

Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-53-45-00-00-00

DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No

IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.5.1

Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255

Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection

Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0E-0C-3D-C9-51

DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No

IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.201

Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.0.0.0

Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.254

DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 127.0.0.1

Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.201

NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

**VPN Client**

PPP adapter VPN Connection 2:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VPN Connection 2

Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :

DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No

Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.5.4(Preferred)

Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255

Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.201

Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.201

NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Answer (score 1):

Please read through [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323441) and [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/292822).

Comment: It's recommended to include the most relevant information from the links in your post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable LAN routing in the properties of the RRAS server.

Comment: I hava mikrotik router before Windows server. Port forwarding works fine, but if i make server act as a router, it confuses mikrotik router (dhcp not working, or blocks all connections to VPN server)